# Why not use always a binomial exact test to compare two proportions instead of chi square?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I am trying to figure out what test I should use in the following scenario: I know that there is a lot of room for improvement in a specific area at work - being extremely critical, let's say that sampling $52$ observations, $31$ could be improved. After instituting an improvement / QA program for six months, let me assume that out of a sample of $55$ cases, there are only $11$ with residual flaws. The two samples are independent.

Although the numbers are exaggerated, I still want to see if the two proportions are statistically different, and I think I have a couple of options: I can run an exact binomial test to calculate the probability that the new proportion of flawed observations, $11/55$, would occur if the actual underlying probability remained $31/52$. Alternatively, I can run a chi-square test.

The chi-square is an approximation, and what I have read is that it is to be applied when the total number of observations is too high. This is clearly not the case in the example; however, playing with the numbers in R, I couldn't see any delay or problems with the results even after using numbers $> 10,000$. And there was no indication of any normal approximation being used.

So, if this is all true, why shouldn't we always opt for an exact binomial test, rather than a chi square?

The code in R would be:

binom.test(c(11, 55 - 11), p = 31/52, alternative ="less")

versus:

prop.test(c(31, 11), c(52, 55), correct = FALSE, alternative = 'greater')

Thank you.